# gunicorn command not found, but it's in my requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, linux, heroku

I am deploying a Django app on Heroku , which is successfully deploying, but I am getting the following error when I want to view the app on the provided http link. `gunicorn` is in my `requirements.txt` file.

```
2020-02-21T16:22:09.021935+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-02-21T16:22:18.635625+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn brendan_project.wsgi -- log file-`
2020-02-21T16:22:20.734759+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2020-02-21T16:22:20.679520+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
```

Here is my `requirements.txt` file:

```
asgiref==3.2.3
astroid==2.3.3
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.2
django-crispy-forms==1.8.1
django-fontawesome==1.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-mailjet==0.3.1
django-sendgrid==1.0.1
django-smtp-ssl==1.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.8
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mailjet-rest==1.3.3
mccabe==0.6.1
psycopg2==2.8.4
pylint==2.4.4
pytz==2019.3
PyYAML==5.3
requests==2.22.0
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
typed-ast==1.4.1
urllib3==1.25.7
whitenoise==5.0.1
```

I also have `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` files.

Comment: Are you using virtualenv/Docker?

Comment: Do you also have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`?

Comment: Did you also *push* the requirements.txt file to Heroku?

Comment: @MarcSances  I am using a virtualenv

Comment: @Chris I have both the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock files

Comment: @GinoMempin I think the requirements.txt file is also pushed since I have connected the repository with the heroku app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I also have `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` files

That's your problem: you're using two different tools that, partly, do the same thing.

If you have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, Heroku uses [Pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to install your dependencies, and your `requirements.txt` will be ignored.

In the absence of a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, Heroku uses `pip` to install dependencies from `requirements.txt`.

Pick a single tool and use it everywhere. If you choose Pipenv, make sure all of your dependencies are reflected in your `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` (e.g. by running `pipenv install -r requirements.txt`), delete your `requirements.txt`, and redeploy. If you want to use `pip`, get rid of your `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`.