# Deploying a Django application to Heroku - No module named 'django_project.wsgi

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a django application but I keep getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_project.wsgi'
```

In fact, here's the full log:

```
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436735+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436735+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436736+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436736+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436736+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436737+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436737+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436738+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436738+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436738+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436740+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436740+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436740+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436741+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436741+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436741+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436742+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436742+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436742+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436742+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436742+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_project.wsgi'
2022-05-13T14:52:06.436801+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-05-13 14:52:06 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-05-13T14:52:06.442147+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-05-13 14:52:06 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 10 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-05-13T14:52:06.541420+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-05-13 14:52:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-05-13T14:52:06.541451+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-05-13 14:52:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2022-05-13T14:52:06.664571+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2022-05-13T14:52:06.894647+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-05-13T14:53:23.778808+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=django-blog-project-laila.herokuapp.com request_id=4a9f0381-627b-4770-9757-93a4faccfe7b fwd="168.195.253.168" dyno= connect=
 service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-13T14:53:23.928270+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=django-blog-project-laila.herokuapp.com request_id=d296d612-ff9c-4ac7-9abd-5742f13cbe8e fwd="168.195.253.168" dyn
o= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-13T14:53:24.335534+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=django-blog-project-laila.herokuapp.com request_id=a5ea86d2-d172-46cd-b77f-978bd1d46d46 fwd="168.195.253.168" dyn
o= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-13T14:53:25.238063+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=django-blog-project-laila.herokuapp.com request_id=1153847b-b0d6-4855-98a8-e4722958b03b fwd="168.195.253.168" dyn
o= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-13T14:52:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

Here's my **Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn django_project.wsgi:application --log-file - --log-level debug
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
manage.py migrate
```

On **settings.py** I have the following:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
    'django-blog-project-laila.herokuapp.com'
]
```

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Here's my **wsgi.py** file:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_project.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Here's my project strucure:

[image]

I've tried moving **Procfile** to the same folder as the **manage.py** file, but then heroku can't locate it.

Here's the log when **Procfile** is located at the same folder as **manage.py**:

```
2022-05-13T19:06:18.510757+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_project.wsgi'
2022-05-13T19:06:18.510820+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-05-13 19:06:18 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2022-05-13T19:06:18.537201+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-05-13 19:06:18 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-05-13T19:06:18.537230+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-05-13 19:06:18 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2022-05-13T19:06:18.730859+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2022-05-13T19:06:18.869100+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-05-13T19:56:41.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user enders.game1990@gmail.com
2022-05-13T19:57:21.664049+00:00 app[api]: Release v11 created by user enders.game1990@gmail.com
2022-05-13T19:57:21.664049+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 699afe79 by user enders.game1990@gmail.com
2022-05-13T19:57:21.837420+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to down
2022-05-13T19:57:24.119910+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=django-blog-project-laila.herokuapp.com request_id=6724bdc4-1598-4fb9-a657-59237254b687 fwd="168.195.253.168" d
yno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-13T19:57:24.994965+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=django-blog-project-laila.herokuapp.com request_id=0fb84b80-c136-409f-bb4d-7cf6b5f1d84f fwd="168.195
.253.168" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-13T19:57:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-05-13T19:57:40.582602+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=django-blog-project-laila.herokuapp.com request_id=e5964c10-21ec-44ad-9440-c00503ac7752 fwd="168.195.253.168" d
yno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-13T19:57:40.834565+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=django-blog-project-laila.herokuapp.com request_id=9f8b5a5c-6dbb-49ba-bfc6-108121e48d91 fwd="168.195
.253.168" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-13T19:57:41.203156+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=django-blog-project-laila.herokuapp.com request_id=bca40057-6e76-446b-8b84-a4c4a5bef659 fwd="168.195
.253.168" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-13T19:57:42.103394+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=django-blog-project-laila.herokuapp.com request_id=04f4c4b0-940e-4c36-a62f-00d874f7f57a fwd="168.195
.253.168" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Edit: With **Procfile** still at **manage.py** folder, I've tried the command `heroku local web` to see if I can run it locally. But I get the following error:

```
[WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
[FAIL] No Procfile and no package.json file found in Current Directory - See run-foreman.js --help
```

I've tried changing **Procfile** to the following:

```
web:gunicorn django_project.wsgi --log-file -
```

But nothing.

Tried running `heroku local web` with **Procfile** in the same level as my git repository (which I'm refering to as the root directory, which is one level above my **manage.py** file) but same error:

```
[WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
[FAIL] No Procfile and no package.json file found in Current Directory - See run-foreman.js --help
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **Procfile** at the root directory (that is, one level above **manage.py**), I've changed its content to the following:

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath django_project django_project.wsgi --log-file -
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19671818/11627241) answer.

Here's my project structure now, just in case it wasn't clear where **Procfile** is located:

[image]

Now everything works as it should.

I'm marking this question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Add runtime.txt with your python version

**runtime.txt**

```
python-"your version"
```

and run

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: I've tried adding a `runtime.txt` file but I still get the same error. And isn't a `requirement.txt` file unnecessary since I already have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`? I'm basing myself on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60467318/11627241) answer for the last bit.

Comment: Oh, you right requirements.txt and Pipfile are the same. 
May be try `web: gunicorn django_project.wsgi--log-file - --log-level debug` without `:application`
Like [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/)

Comment: Tried it without `:application` but it didn't work. I still get the same error.

Comment: May be something with path to wsgi. Try `cd .. && gunicorn project.wsgi:application` or `cd ./project && gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application`. I have no more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure your `Procfile`, `requirements.txt` & `runtime.txt` files are in the same folder as the `manage.py` file.

Your `Procfile` should read as follows:
`web:gunicorn django_project.wsgi --log-file -`

Your `runtime.txt` should read as follows:
`python-versionnumber`. e.g. `python-3.10.2`

Your `requirements.txt` file is necessary as it helps heroku resolve and install packages used in your project.
Run `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Comment: Instead of `requirements.txt` I'm using Pipfile. Although I did try to run exactly as it is but with a `requirement.txt` file and no `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`. No use.

As for the `Procfile` being at the same folder as `manage.py`, I still get the `No module named 'django_project.wsgi'` error, but the log also shows something different: it gives me a `at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running"` error.

Comment: I tried running the command `heroku local web` to see if it's working locally and it tells me that it the `Procfile` is missing:
`[WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
[FAIL] No Procfile and no package.json file found in Current Directory - See run-foreman.js --help`